# Apache conf for setting up variable import or sync with task scheduler

Tags: apache, windows-server

On our server we have an Apache conf file that is used to setup Environment Variables. We needed to create some scheduled task using Task Scheduler to call some PHP methods but some of them are reliant on the Environment Variables.

Because we call PHP directly, the Environment Variables on our Apache config is missing.

Is their a way to enable the Task Scheduler to see the Apache environment variables or a sync with our Windows Server environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering what our solution was. We didn't find any better way rather than declaring the same Apache Environment Variables to our Window Environment Variables.

The downside of doing it this way is that we need to be mindful of changing the environment variables at the same place